# Why does using strcmp in this situation crash my program?

Tags: c++, strcmp

I'm having difficulties using `strcmp`. I make a call in a separate `else` statement (not listed), and it works fine. Is this a possible memory issue?

```
while(inHere == 1)
{
    int numberOfOccupiedTables = 0;

    cout << "\nSelect a table below\n---------------\n\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < tables->size(); i++)
    {
        if(tables->at(i)->open == 0)
        {
            cout << "Table " << tables->at(i)->value << "\n";
            numberOfOccupiedTables++;
        }
    }

    if(numberOfOccupiedTables == 0) 
        cout << "No customers found.\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "(q to back out) Enter number of table: ";
        char* choice = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
        fgets(choice,256,stdin);
        if(strcmp(choice, "q\n") == 0)
            inHere = 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Seems like GIGO: `strcmp()` expects 0-terminated strings.

Comment: When you step to the call to `strcmp`, the pointer and respective memory looks like what?

Comment: I don't suppose you verified the `fgets()` actually *worked* ?

Comment: As an aside, `sizeof(char)` is per definitionem 1, no need to ask.

Comment: Something else to consider is explaining the mixture of C library calls within C++.  The `std::string` could make problems go away.

Comment: The program successfully completes the comparison since I can print strings after the call to strcmp, so that verifies that fgets works correctly as well.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD Those are respected C++ library calls too. Still, changing to a higher layer of abstraction is probably good.

Comment: @user3576841  Why did you allocate memory for `choice`?  All you need to do is declare a char array without calling malloc().  `char choice[256];`

Comment: Nope, flawed reasoning @user3576841. If it fails, the buffer pointed to by `choice` is indeterminate (no idea why you don't use an automatic array there).

Comment: So why do you think the crash is due to `strcmp()` if the program continues? As @OMGtechy asked, what's the error message?

Comment: The very premise of the question is the  `strcmp()` doesn't *return* and the program *crashes* while invoking it. But what did `fgets()` **return** ? (i.e. the consequences of failing to abide by [Henry Spencer's Sixth Commandment](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html)). If it returned an error condition, the output buffer content is *undefined*, and since you never terminate it....

Comment: BTW: Shall `inHere` be a boolean variable (true/false)? In that case, follow the language, only 0 is false, and there is no need to check for !=0 in a conditional expression.

Comment: @WhozCraig note the comment where OP says "I can print strings after the call to strcmp"

Comment: @Deduplicator I like to be language consistent, especially with C++11.  Hopefully user3576841 has a good design reason.  Alternatively, user3576841 will expand thinking about the C++ library more.

Comment: @PaulRoub I noted that while also noting the title of the question, which seems to introduce a bit of a paradox compared with that comment. Its one or the other. I'm almost curious to know which it *really* is.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD It is language consistent, just (possibly) unneccessarily low-level. Still, we cannot know under what burdens the OP labors, nor should we excise parts of C++. Learning of *all* levels is neccessary to ever achieve proficiency.

Comment: The Error that I get after running this (writing in NP++, running the bloodshed dev c++) is that the runtime has ended the program in the unusual manner

Comment: @user3576841 and you believe that's due to `strcmp()` because...?

Comment: Why, where, and with what message? I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

If `fgets()` fails because it reached the end of the file, it will not add a null terminator to the string.  Check to make sure it hasn't returned `NULL` before you do the `strcmp()`.

Comment: Standard quote: The fgets function returns s if successful. If end-of-file is encountered and no
characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and a
null pointer is returned. If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are
indeterminate and a null pointer is returned.

Comment: @Deduplicator I concur. The content does indeed remain unchanged if EOF is reached and nothing has been transferred thus-far. Unfortunately for the OP, that content is entirely indeterminate to begin with if that is indeed happening, per the behavior of `malloc()`.